# Remaining Fractional part in Matlab loop (for function)

Tags: matlab

is there any way that Matlab can deal with the remaining fractional part in Matlab loop. Here is an example:

```
for n=1:3.2
n
end
```

this code returns

```
1
2
3
```

Is there any way to make it return:

```
1
2
3
3.2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = 3.2;
y = unique([1:x x]); % unique() is only need to eliminate duplicate in case
                     % x is an integer
for i = y
  i 
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much